# Enable Multicast on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, network

Following [enabling-multicast-on-your-macos-unix](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2009/11/08/enabling-multicast-on-your-macos-unix/), I am trying to enable multicast on my machine. Firstly, I checked if my network interface supports multicast by running below command:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Output I got is:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether 68:5b:35:d5:26:76 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
```

Then, I added the `multicast` address, using command:

```
sudo route -nv add -net 228.0.0.4 -interface en0
```

Then, I checked if multicast IP is visible in my route table, using command:

```
netstat -nr
```

And yes, there is an entry in my `Routing table`:

```
228.0.0.4/32       68:5b:35:d5:26:76  UmS             0       10     en0
```

Then I run the below command on my mac:

```
ping -t 1 -c 2 228.0.0.4
```

Gives me below result:

```
PING 228.0.0.4 (228.0.0.4): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0

--- 228.0.0.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Then, dropping the IP from Routes Table as follows:

```
 sudo route -v delete -inet 228.0.0.4
```

and added an entry with interface to **en1**:

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a8:bb:cf:20:fb:1a 
    inet6 fe80::aabb:cfff:fe20:fb1a%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.2.124 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 192.168.3.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

then there is an entry in my `Routing table` as below:

```
  228.0.0.4/32       1:0:5e:0:0:4       UmLS            0        0     en1
```

Running `sudo tcpdump -ni en1 host 228.0.0.4` gives me:

```
 tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
 listening on en1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
 15:51:21.962437 IP 192.168.2.124 > 228.0.0.4: ICMP echo request, id 21017, seq 0, length 64
 15:51:22.966098 IP 192.168.2.124 > 228.0.0.4: ICMP echo request, id 21017, seq 1, length 64
```

And running `ping -t 1 -c 2 228.0.0.4` command, gives me below result:

```
PING 228.0.0.4 (228.0.0.4): 56 data bytes

--- 228.0.0.4 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Can anyone help me in enabling the `Multicast`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No IP-address is visible/configured and the status of your en0 is *inactive*.

Adding a route to en0 is obviously possible though. It's still impossible to ping an inactive interface/unreachable network.

Configure an IP-address for en0 and attach it to a network and you should be done. If you have a second Mac configure the same multicast address and check the outgoing pings from the first Mac with `sudo tcpdump -ni en0 host 228.0.0.4`.

Comment: I tried with active interface and still not able to ping. I also updated the question with steps I followed.

Comment: @Arpit The result of your ping should be correct now and multicast is enabled. Just check it with tcpdump!

Comment: `tcpdump` gives me result as posted in updated questions, why I am not able to ping the address `228.0.0.4`?

Comment: @Arpit That's exactly how multicast works! I'll extend my answer as soon as I'm at home again.

Comment: I am having multiple tomcat servers(running on different ports) on the same machine, and when I am starting any of them, I am getting error - `org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl start SEVERE: Unable to join multicast group, make sure your system has multicasting enabled. org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster startInternal SEVERE: Unable to start cluster. org.apache.catalina.tribes.ChannelException: java.net.SocketException: Can't assign requested address; No faulty members identified.`

Comment: @Arpit Would you mind asking a **new** question about the Tomcat servers. With some background information...

Comment: sure, will ask a seperate question, just one thing to confirm one thing, any idea why I am not able to ping multicast address?

Comment: @Arpit I'm still investigating this. Until now I think there is just nothing (e.g. no service running) at "multicast host" 228.0.0.4 which could reply. You can try to ping 224.0.0.251 (that should work) which is tied to Apple Bonjour (running on almost every Mac host).

Comment: make sure you plug in the network cable so that en0 gets active